# How to use SQLite.Net to create, insert and draw data in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and android development. I am making a timetable app and currently have no idea of how to create a database using sqlite.net. Is there possibly any documentation of all the commands that can be used and a thorough description somewhere? Because all i could find are stuffs related to Java, IOS, and other stuffs.

In my app, i need to create, access, insert, modify and draw links between database, I am unsure of how to do any.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQLite.nET is very easy in Xamarin Android/iOS/Forms. Simply add a nuget package "sqlite-net" intp your project. This will add two files, SQLIte.cs and SQliteAsync.cs in your root folder. It uses ORM hance its CRUD functions can be used easily.

Here are few links from Xamarin that will help you understand the concepts better.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/data/sqlite/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/data/sqlite/create_a_database_with_sqlitenet/

EDIT 1:

Include sqlite-net nuget package by Frank Krueger in your application.

Create a file for keeping all Databse related functions. For instance DbOperations.cs

```
    public class DbOperations
    {
        public string SqLiteDBPath { get; private set; }

        public DbOperations()
         {
            string databasePath =   System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), DBConstants.DATABASE_PATH);
                _sqLiteDBFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(databasePath, DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME);
                SqLiteDBPath = databasePath;
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SqLiteDBPath);

                //create database in set path            
                SQLite.SQLite3.Config(SQLite.SQLite3.ConfigOption.Serialized);

                SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(_sqLiteDBFilePath);
                sqLiteConnection.Close();
                CreateTables();
         }

    private void CreateTables()
            {
                SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(_sqLiteDBFilePath);
                sqLiteConnection.CreateTable<User>();
                sqLiteConnection.Close();
            }
    }
```

This snippet will create database and table for object named User in the db.

To perform CRUD operations simply write

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(_sqLiteDBFilePath);
con.Insert(userObject); //Insert
con.Delete(userObject); //Delete
con.DeleteAll<>(); //Delete All rows in table User
con.Update(userObject); //Update
List<User> userList = con.Query<User>("select * from User"); //Select all
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i read those but what i need is a full documentation of all the codes and functions. They didnt exactly explain it fully anyway

Comment: U mean the steps and code snippets to use Sqlite.net?

Comment: Updated this answer. That much is needed to do any operations in Sqlite.net